# Cannot find symbol own class

Tags: java

I've got an package called `superHeroNetwork`. This is the default and only package.

I get the following error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
private ArrayList<superHero> helden;
                  ^
symbol:   class superHero
location: class superHeroNetworkSystem
```

Witch would suggest that the `superHero` class cannot be found. But the class exists in the same package.

I've tried to import all classes of the package ( `import superHeroNetwork.*;`) but that didn't fixed the problem to.

The file `superHero.java`:

```
package superHeroNetwork;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class superHero {

    private String naam;
    private ArrayList<String> superKrachten;
    public ArrayList<superHero> vrienden;

    public superHero(String naam){
        this.naam = naam;
        this.superKrachten = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.vrienden = new ArrayList<superHero>();
    }
}
```

And the file `superHeroNetworkSystem.java`:

```
package superHeroNetwork;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class superHeroNetworkSystem {

    private ArrayList<superHero> helden;

    public superHeroNetworkSystem(){
        this.helden = new ArrayList<superHero>();
    }

    public void voegSuperheldToe(superHero held){
        this.helden.add(held);
    } 

    public void voegVriendschapToe(superHero vriend1, superHero vriend2){
        if(!vriend1.vrienden.contains(vriend2)){
            vriend1.addFriend(vriend2);
            vriend2.addFriend(vriend1);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Jullie zijn al vrienden!");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm clueless right now on how to fix this problem. How can i solve this particular problem?

Comment: Are you using an IDE or compiling through cmd?

Comment: How do you compile you program?

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling from the source directory?

Comment: @user7, I'm using javatar in Sublime Text 3

Comment: @MarounMaroun, wow... Was it really that simple????

Comment: Bad practice found :dont name your class in `camel case` (superHeroNetworkSystem ,superHero)

Comment: @MarounMaroun, If you could make an answer of it, I can mark this as answerd

Comment: Your code looks no okej, except your class name should start with a capital letter

Comment: @SanKrish, alright. It should start with an uppercase, but what about the rest? all small letters?

Comment: @Matlight This will help you http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: Btw, there *is* a command line option to look in a different directory for source files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not compiling from the source directory.

I would like to add some few notes:

- follow [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) and rename your class to `SuperHero` also change your package name
- do you really want `vrienden` to be `public` member of the class? I'm not sure about what your class suppose to do, but looks like you can improve it (think about *getters* and *setters*)

Comment: About point 2... You're right. I should make an getter / setter for it. That's way better